# How to return to a previous bullet point type after pressing tab to nest bullet points

Tags: libreoffice

So I'm writing in LibreOffice (Version 4.0.2.2) and I start a bulleted list like so:

- List item 1
- List item 2
- List item 3

But I notice I want a sub list nested in list item 3, so I press return and then tab and carry on, like so:

- List item 1
- List item 2
- List item 3

  - List item 3.1
  - List item 3.2
  - List item 3.3

And then I am done with my nested list and want to continue my list, how do I do this?

- List item 1
- List item 2
- List item 3

  - List item 3.1
  - List item 3.2
  - List item 3.3
- List item 4
- List item 5

Comment: I guess I could just end the list there and make a new list, but I would like to continue *that* list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the same way you made the sub list except with <kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>tab</kbd> instead of <kbd>tab</kbd>. So hit <kbd>enter</kbd> to get a new point and <kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>tab</kbd> to move it one level up.